# How could I connect php to SQL Server?

Tags: php, sql-server

I'm trying to connect on windows 
my php code with SQL Server(windows authentication). I am using xampp.

This is my code but it's not working.

```
<?php
          $dbPassword = "";
           $dbUserName = "Inspiron/Malky";
           $dbServer = "localhost";
           $dbName = "person";     

//       $conn = mysqli_connect($dbServer , $dbUserName , $dbPassword,$dbName) or die("unable to connect to host"); 

       $connectionInfo = array( "Database"=>$dbName);
       $conn = sqlsrv_connect( $dbServer, $connectionInfo);

if( $conn ) {
     echo "Connection established.<br />";
}else{
     echo "Connection could not be established.<br />";
     die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
}
?>
```

ERROR

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function sqlsrv_connect() in C:\xampp\htdocs\connection\connection.php:12 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\connection\phpAdd.php(2): require() #1 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\connection\connection.php on line 12
```

Could someone help my or give me some links to read?

Comment: What is 'not working'? What is the exact error or behaviour that you don't expect?

Comment: when i try to add my form i get an error

Comment: ERROR   Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function sqlsrv_connect() in C:\xampp\htdocs\connection\connection.php:12 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\connection\phpAdd.php(2): require() #1 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\connection\connection.php on line 12

Comment: this might help - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13703824/php-iis7-mssql-call-to-undefined-function-sqlsrv-connect

Comment: that link is about pdo i don't use pdo

Comment: am i supposed to download something.

Comment: have you checked if the sqlsrv dll driver entry is in your php.ini file?
You can find more information about the drivers here: https://www.php.net/manual/en/sqlsrv.installation.php

Comment: deleted it. could you help me find my mistake

Comment: The error says `sqlsrv_connect is undefined` so my guess is that whatever package includes that (I'm not familiar with PHP) is missing or incorrectly installed.

Comment: Please take the time to read [ask] and [mcve]

Comment: @MStern What is your PHP version? Thanks.

Comment: @Zhorov PHP Version 7.3.3

Comment: @Zhorov downloaded PHP version 5.6

Comment: @MStern Then use PHP Driver for SQL Server 3.2, if you mean PHP version 5.6. For PHP 7.3+, use PHP Driver for SQL Server 5.6

Comment: @Zhorov am i supposed to put them in a certian file ?

Comment: @Zhorov I just download them and it's supposed to work?

Comment: @Zhorov I should extract files from PHP Driver for SQL Server 5.6 ?

Comment: @Zhorov how do i Move the Driver File into my Extension Directory? through command prompt?

Comment: @MStern Just copy the dll files.

Comment: @Zhorov I added the files what am i supposed to do now?

Answer (score 0):

What the environment? Windows OS Server, Linux (what flavor), MAC OS. If not using MAMP, LAMP, then what web service components are you using?

Post the log file from php that outputs the log/error messages.

Check if sql files exist needed for php such as a directory containing for example;

```
php_sqlsrv_7_nts.signature
php_sqlsrv_7_nts.so
php_sqlsrv_7_ts.signature
php_sqlsrv_7_ts.so
```

I found for Linux and for Windows platforms, the SQL drivers need to be installed.  You may have to install sql drivers and odbc drivers if you haven't already.  Other great documentation located at:

Example application (SQLSRV Driver)
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/php/example-application-sqlsrv-driver?view=sql-server-2017

How to Install sqlsrv driver on MAMP Mac OS Laravel 2018
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PRH04PxZpUk&feature=youtu.be

Ubuntu Linux
https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/sql-server/developer-get-started/php/ubuntu/

Download Drivers for PHP for SQL Server
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/php/download-drivers-php-sql-server?view=sql-server-2017

ODBC Driver, see example
https://github.com/Microsoft/msphpsql/releases/tag/v5.3.0

If using Ubuntu Linux, did you bind mssql to php/appache? For example,

```
apt-cache search mssql
```

This will show the database packages

```
sudo apt-get install freetds-common freetds-bin unixodbc php5-sybase
```

To test connection to SQL:

```
tsql -H 10.192.0.10 -p 1433 -U UserAccount -P yourpasswrd -D dbsource
```

Simple test using php;

```
<?php
function ConnectDB() {
$conn = mssql_connect(“10.192.0.10”, “UserAccount”, 
“yourpasswrd”);
return $conn;
}
?>
```

Comment: I'm using windows

Comment: Do you see the sql drivers in the directory for php in the windows machine?

for example I show under: .../bin/php/7.1.5/ext

php_sqlsrv_7_nts_x64.dll
php_sqlsrv_7_nts_x86.dll
php_sqlsrv_7_ts_x64.dll
php_sqlsrv_71_ts_x86.dll
php_sqlsrv_71_nts_x86.dll
php_sqlsrv_71_ts_x64.dll
php_sqlsrv_71_ts_x86.dll

[link]https://github.com/Microsoft/msphpsql

Comment: i downloaded msodbcsql_17.3.1.1_X64.msi and SQLSRV30. what am i supposed to do now?

Comment: @MStern Edit php.ini - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/php/loading-the-php-sql-driver?view=sql-server-2017#loading-the-driver-at-php-startup

Comment: @Zhorov I added the extension and it's still not working

Comment: @Zhorov This is where i copied my  dll files.  C:\xampp\php  . Is this correct?