# Connect PHP with SQL Server 2000

Tags: php, sql-server

I want to connect PHP with SQL Server 2000. I have search how to connect it and find this code:

```
$dsn="MY-PC\MSSQLServer";
$username="sa";
$password="admin";
$database = "perpus";
$sqlconnect=odbc_connect("Driver={SQL Server};Server=$dsn;Database=$database;", $username, $password);
$sqlquery="SELECT * FROM TDenda;";
$process=odbc_exec($sqlconnect, $sqlquery);

while(odbc_fetch_row($process)){
$companyName = odbc_result($process,"denda_perhari");
echo "$companyName<br>"; }
odbc_close($sqlconnect);
```

When I run it on browser, it result this:

```
Warning: odbc_connect(): SQL error: [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][DBMSLPCN]Invalid connection., SQL state 08001 in SQLConnect in C:\xampp\htdocs\perpus\config.php on line 6

Warning: odbc_exec() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in C:\xampp\htdocs\perpus\config.php on line 8

Warning: odbc_fetch_row() expects parameter 1 to be resource, null given in C:\xampp\htdocs\perpus\config.php on line 10

Warning: odbc_close() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in C:\xampp\htdocs\perpus\config.php on line 13
```

Did anyone know how to connect it correctly? I already tried change MSSQLServer to SQLEXPRESS but still not working.

===UPDATE

I change to sqlsrv, already install the driver and extension. Here's my new code

```
<?php
$serverName = "MY-PC\MSSQLSERVER";
$connectionInfo = array( "Database"=>"perpus", "UID"=>"sa", "PWD"=>"perpus");
$conn = sqlsrv_connect( $serverName, $connectionInfo);

if( $conn ) {
     echo "Connection established.<br />";
}else{
     echo "Connection could not be established.<br />";
     die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
}
?>
```

And it resulted:

> Connection could not be established. Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] =>
>   08001 [SQLSTATE] => 08001 [1] => 87 [code] => 87 [2] =>
>   [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server]SQL Server Network
>   Interfaces: Connection string is not valid [87]. [message] =>
>   [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server]SQL Server Network
>   Interfaces: Connection string is not valid [87]. ) [1] => Array ( [0]
>   => HYT00 [SQLSTATE] => HYT00 [1] => 0 [code] => 0 [2] => [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server]Login timeout expired
>   [message] => [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server]Login timeout
>   expired ) [2] => Array ( [0] => 08001 [SQLSTATE] => 08001 [1] => 87
>   [code] => 87 [2] => [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server]A
>   network-related or instance-specific error has occurred while
>   establishing a connection to SQL Server. Server is not found or not
>   accessible. Check if instance name is correct and if SQL Server is
>   configured to allow remote connections. For more information see SQL
>   Server Books Online. [message] => [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 11 for SQL
>   Server]A network-related or instance-specific error has occurred while
>   establishing a connection to SQL Server. Server is not found or not
>   accessible. Check if instance name is correct and if SQL Server is
>   configured to allow remote connections. For more information see SQL
>   Server Books Online. ) )

I believe that my instance and server name is correct. So I have no idea why it always failed

Comment: I am really not too familiar with SQL Server, but are you sure the DSN exists and that the username/password are correct?

Comment: You may also want to read this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13756696/811240

Comment: @Mike Yes, already correct.
I'm trying use sqlserv but the browser return : sqlserv is not a function

Comment: That's because `sqlserv` is not a function. See: http://php.net/sqlsrv (note, there is no 'e') for the `sqlsrv_*` functions and documentation. Or give PDO a try if you want.

Comment: Hello, I already installed sqlsrv, and now my result being more confused: SQL Server Network Interfaces: Connection string is not valid. Does my instance name is wrong?

Comment: You don't need an odbc interface to connect from PHP to SQL Server. Use sqlsrv driver and have a look at examples in this article http://php.net/manual/en/function.sqlsrv-fetch-array.php

Comment: @CrossVander Then you probably have an invalid connection string. Make sure it follows the format outlined here (assuming you're using `sqlsrv_connect()`): http://php.net/manual/en/function.sqlsrv-connect.php

Comment: @Mike Check my updated code. Already same with that link.

Comment: @DmitryPolyakov check my updated code

Comment: I think the error is pretty self-explanatory. Seems as if you have an incorrect value for `$serverName`. Make sure the server name, instance name and port number (default is 1433) are all correct. Also, I'm not sure if these are case-sensitive, but to be sure, use the same case that they were registered with. I see both your examples use different casing.

Comment: all correct, until I change my servername to (local) then I got this error: "ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server does not support connections to SQL Server 2000 or earlier versions". Now I know the problem from beginning is the driver. Do You know what driver that I need?

Comment: It gives you that error using sqlsrv functions?

Comment: Yes. Or do You know which ODBC version that I need?

Comment: Maybe this article might help: http://craigballinger.com/blog/2011/08/usin-php-5-3-with-mssql-pdo-on-windows/

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/90574/discussion-between-cross-vander-and-mike).